# Selenium refused connection when adding webdriverwait function to load href page

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm running into a "connection refused" error when adding a WebDriverWait function to my webscraping.

I've checked different online posts about this issue, but there's many different types of problems people are having, and I haven't come across one that has helped me.

The following is the added code to my program which causes my issue. Without it, my chrome webdriver loads, and I'm able to grab information from the current webpage. The  tag  in the following code has an unusual class name, but what it's doing it linking to another webpage which has the information I need. My webdriver is failing to access the page. The class is correct, and the tag name is also correct (containing the href)

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Fz(15px) D(ib) Td(inh)']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    browser.quit()
```

Here are the errors it causes

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\misha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    159             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 160                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001C37CF0F9B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Oh also I imported expected_conditions as EC